# Combat System for a Javascript/Jquery RPG Game (Timers)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started learning javascript about a month ago. I've been working on a personal project to help me hone my skils and have decided to make a text-based RPG Game.

What I want to achieve is a combat system based on a "tick" system or time. Basically once combat is initiated (by attacking) the ticks would initiate and the enemy would attack me every 3 ticks(seconds) or so. How often the enemy attacks would also be based on their agility stat.

As of right now, I have a basic combat system that attacks the enemy for a random value based on the player's strength and enemies defense values. However, the enemy only attacks back once I attack them, and its instantaneously. Here's the code for that.

```
regPlayerAttack = function () {
    //random boolean to determine if its going to be 10% dmg of positive or 
negative
    randomDmgFlag = Math.round(Math.random());
    //the 10% will be added on
    if (randomDmgFlag === 1) {
        rawDmg = Math.round((player.level * 3 + player.strength * 8) - 
(chosenEnemy.stamina * 2));
        randomDmgRange = (15.0 / 100) * rawDmg;
        randomDmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomDmgRange - 0) + 0);
        totalDmg = rawDmg + randomDmg;
        chosenEnemy.health -= totalDmg;
        $("#textbox-text").prepend("You attacked the " + chosenEnemy.name + 
" for " + totalDmg + " damage." + "<br>");
    }
    //the 10% will be subtracted
    else {
        rawDmg = Math.round((player.level * 3 + player.strength * 8) - 
(chosenEnemy.stamina * 2));
        randomDmgRange = (15.0 / 100) * rawDmg;
        randomDmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomDmgRange - 0) + 0);
        totalDmg = rawDmg - randomDmg;
        chosenEnemy.health -= totalDmg;
        $("#textbox-text").prepend("You attacked the " + chosenEnemy.name + 
" for " + totalDmg + " damage." + "<br>");
    }
}
```

I have the same function for the enemy attack that works exactly like the code above. (I know I should make it into one function, but I wanted to visualize it first)

So to sum it up, I want a way for the enemy to keep attacking me once combat has been initiated based on a time system and they'll attack faster or slower based on their agility stat. I'm still messing with damage formulas so nothing is set in stone. Any ideas?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a turn counter and an interval which triggers every second (or whatever you want). When a character's `turn % agility === 0`, that character attacks. (eg, agility of 1 would mean the character attacks every turn - agility of 3 would mean the character attacks every 3 turns)

```js
const enemies = [
  { agility: 3, name: 'enemy1', hp: 100 }
];
const player = { agility: 1 };

let turn = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.clear();
  console.log('turn ' + turn);
  // player attacks every turn with agility 1:
  regPlayerAttack();
  
  // if all enemies are dead, end the interval
  if (enemies.every(({ hp }) => hp <= 0)) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('done');
  }

  // every enemy whose agility modulo the current turn is 0 attacks:
  enemies
    .filter(({ agility }) => turn % agility === 0)
    .forEach(enemyAttack);
  
  turn++;
}, 1000);

function regPlayerAttack() {
  console.log('player attacking...');
  // insert attack logic
}
function enemyAttack(enemy) {
  console.log(enemy.name + ' attacking...');
  // insert attack logic
}
```

Note that like this, agility is inversely proportional to speed - lower agility is better. This makes the calculations really easy to visualize when there are no fractions involved, but if you want higher agility to correspond to higher speed, you can change the formula as you like.